# breadcrumb in OSClass

Tags: breadcrumbs, osclass

I'm new for OSClass.
I saw

`$breadcrumb = osc_breadcrumb('&raquo;', false);`

in `header.php`. Where `osc_breadcrumb()` is define? I'm using `modern` theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function osc_breadcrumb() is declared at oc-includes/osclass/helpers/hDefines.php

and returns html code,

If you want to take a deeper look Breadcrumb.php class is located at oc-includes/osclass/classes/Breadcrumb.php

Answer (score 0):

In Osclass 8.2, much more options has been added into breadcrumbs and modifying core files may not be needed anymore.
New settings can be found in Backoffice > Settings > Breadcrumbs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).